# How can I save an email instead of sending when using SmtpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I am using SmtpClient to send an email with an attachment.
However for a certain batch we need to somehow save the MailMessage instead of sending them.
We are then thinking/hoping to manually upload the messages to the users drafts folder.

Is it possible to save these messages with the attachment intact (impossible, I would have thought). Or alternatively upload the messages to a folder in the users account?

If anyone has any experience of this, I'd much appreciate a bit of help or a pointer.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

When testing in ASP.NET we save our emails to a folder rather then send them through an email server. Maybe you could change your`web.config` settings like this for your batch?

```xml
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
      <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\Temp\mail\"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

**Additional Info:**

- [MSDN: <specifiedPickupDirectory> Element (Network Settings)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164241.aspx)
- [Configuring SmtpClient to drop emails in a folder on disk](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/01/configuring-smtpclient-to-drop-emails.html)

Comment: Thanks worked a treat. Also Avram (see below) posted a useful link which discusses changing the email message name from the auto generated GUID to your own value.

Comment: I have tried this method, and I get an error that a "From" address is not specified.  Is there a way to specify this for SpecifiedPickupDirectory in web.config? When you do network settings there is

Answer (score 14):

As well as the `SpecifiedPickupDirectory` information of the other answers, if you want to ensure your emails are sent to a folder relative to the site root - handy in testing on build servers where you don't know the paths - you can add a quick check in your email sending code:

```
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    ...

    // Add "~" support for pickupdirectories.
    if (client.DeliveryMethod == SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory && client.PickupDirectoryLocation.StartsWith("~"))
    {
        string root = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string pickupRoot = client.PickupDirectoryLocation.Replace("~/", root);
        pickupRoot = pickupRoot.Replace("/",@"\");
        client.PickupDirectoryLocation = pickupRoot;
    }
```

And your tests will look something like this (make sure you use App_Data so IIS can write to the folder):

```
    // Arrange - get SitePath from AppDomain.Current.BaseDirectory + ..\
    string pickupPath = Path.Combine(SitePath, "App_Data", "TempSmtp");
    if (!Directory.Exists(pickupPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pickupPath);

    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(pickupPath, "*.eml"))
    {
        File.Delete(file);
    }

    // Act (send some emails)

    // Assert
    Assert.That(Directory.GetFiles(pickupPath, "*.eml").Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
```

Comment: Good one. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

This can help - [Adding Save() functionality to Microsoft.Net.Mail.MailMessage](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/smtpclientext.aspx?display=PrintAll&fid=1533533&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2876398)
The main ideia, make an extension to MailMessage ,that by reflection making a save method.

Comment: Thanks, it will be interesting to see whether I can add attachments here too.

Answer (score 6):

You can configure this with the `system.net` setting in your `web.config` / `app.config` file.

```xml
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
      <network host="mail.mydomain.com" port="25" />
    </smtp>
    <!-- Use this setting for development
    <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
      <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Temp" />
    </smtp>
    -->
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Also, here's a link with info on [migrating from `System.Web.Mail` to `System.Net.Mail`](http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2006/04/23/Migrating-from-System.Web.Mail-to-System.Net.Mail.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A bug also requires adding  as a workaround in some versions of the framework. So the completed version looks like:

```xml
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\Temp\mail\"/>
        <network host="localhost" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```