# How do I set up my Windows 7 Enterprise machine as an SMTP server to test?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

Is this possible?  Basically trying to test emails being sent through an SMTP server, I know all the "yea, but it's not the same as a real...", but is it possible, and how?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567765/how-can-i-save-an-email-instead-of-sending-when-using-smtpclient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is only for testing I would definitely use a dummy SMTP server that doesn't actually send the Emails but just stores them locally, and it's a lot easier to setup, something like this: http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/

Otherwise: http://www.hmailserver.com/index.php?page=welcome